# Twitter API working fron development server but not from GAE (Google App Engine)

Tags: api, google-app-engine, python-2.7, twitter

I am trying to access Twitter API from GAE (Google App Engine), however it works from development environment but not in production environment. Code is this:

This is the code:

```
import requests,sys
sys.path.insert(0,'requests_oauthlib')
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
from urlparse import parse_qs

REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"

CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxx"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxx"
OAUTH_TOKEN = "xxxx"
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = "xxxx"

oauth = OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY, client_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
r = requests.post(url=REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, auth=oauth)
print r
```

After running the code in GAE I receive:

```
<Response [403]>
```

But after running the same code in development environment I receive:

```
<Response [200]>
```

What is the difference?
Why in GAE twitter response is 403, but from my dev env I receive 200?

(For a better reference my settings in twitter does not include a callback URL.)

Comment: What is the response message?

Answer (score 0):

Response 403 is the response from twitter when the request is made from GAE. (And the response is correct 200 when is sent from my development server).

As far as I understand response 403 is:
"403 Forbidden
The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead."
(This was taken from this link: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

In the other hand Response 200:
"200 OK
The request has succeeded."

The point is, when production server (GAE PAAS Platform) makes the request, Why response from twitter is 403 (Forbiden), but when is made from dev server response is correct (200)?

Why twitter API is doing some kind of difference depending on who makes the request?.

In twitter API settings I authorized the application in GAE.

I wonder what is the difference.